# Can LLMRequestsChain work with llm_chain created by using LCEL syntax?

Tags: langchain

`
# Created  LLMRequestsChain chain this way works
chain = LLMRequestsChain(llm_chain=LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt))

```
# Created chain this way also works
llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
chain = LLMRequestsChain(llm_chain=llm_chain)

# But Created chain using LCEL syntax does not work
llm_chain = prompt | llm
chain = LLMRequestsChain(llm_chain=llm_chain)
```

`

The error is:
`5 validation errors for LLMRequestsChain llm_chain -> prompt field required (type=value_error.missing) llm_chain -> llm field required (type=value_error.missing) llm_chain -> first extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra) llm_chain -> last extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra) llm_chain -> middle extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)`

Is it requirement to use LLMChain when creating LLMRequestsChain?
I am hoping I can use the new LCEL syntax when creating the llm_chain to pass in to LLMRequestsChain
langchain 0.0.352